# Using Android app to manipulate Webpages

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I used to know of Selenium and WebDriver which allowed through code to manipulate webpage elements such as Textfields and Buttons, but i am not sure if these tools exist now or are relevant.

Say for example, i have a button on my app that does a specific search on Google

**1)** Enter `www.google.com`

**2)** Enter Text in the Search field

**3)** simulate a button click (Search)

Comment: your post does not appear to be a question. What do you want to do? Modify the results? Display results different? Are you trying to build a browser?

Comment: I am trying to make an app that can browse a website(existing) and interact with its elements like text fields and buttons. Not building a new browser nor trying to manipulate results. The google search example above demonstrates entering text in the search field and then clicking search. All this simulated through code on the android app

Comment: you can get text and use libs like OkHttp to send it to a server.. or use a WebView to emulate a browser as mentioned in one answer.. if neither of those are what you want to do, you need to give more info on what you are trying to accomplish. You still don't actually ask a question above. Like "interact with its elements" isn't clear. When you get HTML back you can parse and do what you want and then display it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebView and inject JavaScript. You will need to set a JavaScript Interface to interact between native android code and the webpage.